# Error not found value context?

Tags: scala, playframework, websocket, actor, chatroom

```
def join(username: String): scala.concurrent.Future[(Iteratee[JsValue, _], Enumerator[JsValue])] = {
  println("friend name in model" + username)
  val first = Akka.system.actorOf(Props[ChatRoom2], name = username)
  println("this is chat room two default")
}
```

and when i use this   `val first = context.actorOf(Props[ChatRoom2],name=username)`

I am use this for create a child actor in a different chat room but it shows an error not found value context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

import akka.actor

Refer this url 
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/akka-user/4eYJWKWhAe8/TTAIOAI-uaIJ

Comment: Check if you extends Actor class to your class

Comment: Yes i extends Actor class in my class and i also have an object of this class in which i use this join code.

Comment: I agree with @SKarthik's comment. Do you mean, you extend Actor class on ChatRoom2 or on the class having join method above?

Comment: Yes i extends Actor class on my class ChatRoom2.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot access actor `context` from a class not extending `Actor`. You must be extending `Actor` in the class having `join` method above (not only ChatRoom2)

Answer (score 3):

When you use an actor `system` reference, you're creating "top level" actors, whereas using `context` creates "child actors" of your current actor. This means that accessing `context` only makes sense from within an `Actor`.

Here's an example:

```
val system = ActorSystem("name")
val act = system.actorOf(classOf[SomeActor])

class SomeActor extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case _ => val child = context.actorOf(...)
  }
}
```

In this example "act" is a "top level" actor, and "child" is a child of "act", because it was created by act's context.

I hope this helps!

For more help please refer to the docs: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.1/scala/actors.html